Derivation with respect to product of variables
I have three variables $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ that describe my system, and two additional functions:
$$u(x,y): \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}\to\mathbb{R}^3$$
$$v(x,y): \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}\to\mathbb{R}^3$$
I also have some function $f(v(x,y), z): \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}\to\mathbb{R}$.
I am trying to compute $$\frac{\partial f(v(x,y), z)}{\partial h(u,v,z)}$$  with $h(u,v,z) = u(x,y) + zv(x,y)$.
I have $$\frac{\partial f(v(x,y),z)}{\partial h(u,v,z)}= \frac{\partial f(v(x,y),z)}{\partial v(x,y)}\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial h(x,y,z)}$$
with $$v(x,y) = \frac{h(x,y,z) - u(x,y)}{z}$$ and therefore $$\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial h(x,y,z)}= \frac{1}{z}$$
Finally,
$$\frac{\partial f(v(x,y),z)}{\partial h(u,v,z)}= \frac{\partial f(v(x,y),z)}{\partial v(x,y)}\frac{1}{z}$$
I am really not sure about the part where I take the partial derivative of $v$ with respect to $h$ since $h$ is a function of $v$.
Does that make sense or is it a mistake? I also don't see logically why it wouldn't be possible.

It seems correct, but $h$ contributes to $f$ through $z$ similarly, that is why you need to add the term $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial h}$ to the final result, with $\frac{\partial z}{\partial h} = \frac{1}{\partial h / \partial z} = \frac{1}{v}$.
